# FileReference.load() does not as excepted

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, ria

I used Flash player 10, and Flex SDK 3.4.  The code as followings:

```
// Following comes callbacks
function imageLoadOpenCallback(evt:Event):void
{
    trace("in--open");
}

function imageLoadCompleteCallback(evt:Event):void
{
    trace("in--load");
    var fr:FileReference = evt.target as FileReference;
    trace(fr.data);
}

function imageLoadErrorCallback(evt:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("in--ioerror");
}

function imageSelectCancelCallback(evt:Event):void
{
    trace("in cancel");
}

function imageSelectCallback(evt:Event):void
{
    trace("in -- select");
    for (var i:int=0; i<frl.fileList.length; i++)
    {

        frl.fileList[i].addEventListener(Event.OPEN, imageLoadOpenCallback);
        frl.fileList[i].addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoadCompleteCallback);
        frl.fileList[i].addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, imageLoadErrorCallback);
        frl.fileList[i].load();
        trace(frl.fileList[i]);
        trace(frl.fileList[i].creationDate);
        trace(frl.fileList[i].creator);
        trace(frl.fileList[i].data);
        trace(frl.fileList[i].name);
    }   
}


// Following comes UI handlers
function onAddPictures():void
{
    var imageFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.png");
    frl.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, imageSelectCallback);
    frl.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, imageSelectCancelCallback);
    frl.browse([imageFilter]);
}
```

Only the imageSelectCancelCallback handler get called when I select some files in the dialog. But no load/open/io_error handler get called at all. I have Google some code example, in which it used FileReference instead of FileReferenceList. I don't know the reason, could you please help me?

Comment: Could you please format yor code correctly?

Comment: The code above, copied into my project, is functioning exactly as I'd expect--the select handler is called when I click OK, the load handler is called after each individual file has been loaded.

Answer (score 2):

In Air the `fileReference` objects in `fileReferenceList` do not fire the complete event when doing `fileList[i].load()`. In a Flex project it works fine. Adobe has not responded to bug reports on this appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in your compiler settings for flex, that you have at least 10.0.0 for "Use a specific version".

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to use `FileReferenceList` instead of `FileReference` would be if you need to upload multiple files at once. If you only want to allow uploading one file at once, simply use `FileReference`.

Some clarification: `imageSelectCallback()`, and NOT `imageSelectCancelCallback()`, should get called when you select some files in the file browser AND click OK. `imageSelectCancelCallback()` is only called when you click Cancel.

Other than that, I never used the `load()` API, but I did use the `upload(URLRequest)` API. I am not sure what's your use case, but if you need to upload an image to a server, you should use the `upload()` method.

Speaking of upload events, I experienced some reliability issues when listening to `Event.COMPLETE` events, so I actually got better results listening to `DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA`.